# Adding comments into Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick-3.0

Is there a way I can add comments into the sql that is formed by slick without writing a raw sql statement? This is to keep track of the code in application that launched the sql.

Comment: Could you give some example, exactly how you mean

Comment: Something similar to this https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/comments.php

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say no. Currently in the `3.3.1` version of *Slick*, there is no way to add a comment to queries other that creating the SQL code by hand.

It may be get added later as there is an open issue years ago for that:

https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/468

Answer (score 0):

We accomplished this by downcasting DBIOAction and using SqlAction.overrideStatements:

```scala
val databaseAction: DBIOAction[A, NoStream, E] = ??? // your action 
val comment: String = ??? // your comment
val annotatedAction = databaseAction match {
      case sqlAction: SqlAction[A, NoStream, E] => sqlAction.overrideStatements(sqlAction.statements.map { s =>
        "/* " + comment + " */ " + s
      })
      case otherAction => otherAction
    }

db.run(annotatedAction)
```

It causes all SQL statements to be prefixed with a comment.  You can make the comment be some unique identifier to help you connect SQL to your code, or you could do it automatically by finding a relevant stack frame in `Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace` before running the query.